# Is there a common name for Beaumontia Wall/Beaumontia grandiflora Wall?

Tags: vines, terminology

I'm looking for a common name for Beaumontia Wall/Beaumontia grandiflora Wall.

[Top Tropicals](https://toptropicals.com/catalog/uid/Beaumontia_grandiflora.htm) lists:

> Beaumontia grandiflora, Echites grandiflora
>
> Family: Apocynaceae
>
> Easter Lily Vine, Heralds Trumpet, Nepal Trumpet Flower

I'm not totally sure that Easter Lily Vine, Heralds Trumpet, Nepal Trumpet Flower
actually **do** equate to Beaumontia Wall/Beaumontia grandiflora Wall though.

Is there a common name for Beaumontia Wall/Beaumontia grandiflora Wall?

Answer (score 2):

Common names never identify exactly a species.

Usually a common name refers to many similar species (and often also to non really similar species) or to different species on different continents.

When the name is made by two or more word, in particular with "vine", "wild", "of forest", the link to a single species is very difficult. It really depends on the region you are living. And "Lily", "Rose", "Cactus", "Apple", "Nuts" are overloaded names.

Common gardening flowers [flowers in shops] tend to have only one well-know name (especially annual plants) [which could be different on the name you used in past], but I see often that gardening shops add the scientific name, to be sure to have the same understanding.

Note: **cultivar name** look like the common names, but it usually identify exactly only a cultivar

Answer (score 2):

Looking for pinpoint accuracy in a common name is pointless - common names for plants vary from region to region, country to country, which is why you have three common names for the same plant already.

The botanical or Latin name for a plant, in its entirety, is the only way to ever be sure what the plant is, right down to the specific variety or cultivar. Common names for plants are often unhelpful - for instance, in the UK, Bouncing Bet is the common name for a particular plant in the South of the country, but further north, the same plant is referred to as Tumbling Ted. Further, some common names are also applied to as many as three or more entirely different, unrelated plants.

Essentially, if plants are referred to by their common names only, no one ever really knows exactly which plant is meant - in theory, you could call a plant Fred Jones and if you said it often enough to as many people as possible, that name, over time, would become accepted as the plant's name in your locality. Personally, I feel strongly about the use of common names; I find them incredibly irritating because they're unclear and confusing. It's rather like having a conversation with someone who's talking about Tom's behaviour, and eventually you realise they're referring to their pet lizard, not their partner.

There may well be other common names for Beaumontia, but clearly, the three you already have are the most well known ones.